# How to create a control for panning and tilt together?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to create a control in my WPF app that allows the user to drag a dot inside a box/circle. This will be used to drive the pan and tilt values for a camera.

I am not sure how to create a control like that. The picture below is an example of the type of control that I want to develop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick solution to get you started.

For the XAML, I've used an `Ellipse` control for the "dot". The Ellipse is placed inside a `Canvas` control (which allows the dot to be moved around):-

```
<Grid Background="White"
      MouseUp="ParentOnMouseUp">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" 
            Background="Green"
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            MouseMove="CanvasOnMouseMove">

        <!-- Implement your blue circle b/g as an Image control here ... />

        <Ellipse x:Name="dot"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Fill="Blue"
                 Loaded="DotOnLoaded"
                 MouseDown="DotOnMouseDown"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

First I handle the Ellipse's `MouseDown` event:

```
private void DotOnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _isDraggingDot = true;
}
```

All I do here is set a flag to indicate that I'm starting to drag the dot.

Next, I handle the *Canvas* `MouseMove` event, which is where I move the dot around. It includes logic to ensure the dot doesn't stray outside the canvas:

```
private void CanvasOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isDraggingDot)
    {
        var mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        var x = mousePos.X;
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (x > canvas.Width)
        {
            x = canvas.Width;
        }

        var y = mousePos.Y;
        if (y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        if (y > canvas.Height)
        {
            y = canvas.Height;
        }

        dot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - (dot.Width / 2.0)); // offset ensures dot is centred on mouse pointer
        dot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - (dot.Height / 2.0));
        }
    }
```

This is also where you would calculate the dot's vertical and horizontal offset from centre, and use these values to update the pan and tilt.

Finally, I implement the `MouseUp` event on the outer control (the Grid in my example):

```
private void ParentOnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _isDraggingDot = false;
    CentreDot();
}

private void CentreDot()
{
    dot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (canvas.Width / 2.0) - (dot.Width / 2.0));
    dot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (canvas.Height / 2.0) - (dot.Height / 2.0));
}
```

The reason for handling the event on the outer control is to ensure that the dot is returned to the centre if the user releases the mouse button outside the Canvas.
(Note that I also set a b/g colour on the Grid, otherwise it defaults to transparent and won't detect mouse events!)

Lastly I wire up the Ellipse's `Loaded` event to initially centre the dot when the UI loads:

```
private void DotOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CentreDot();
}
```

As I mentioned, this is just a quick solution where the dot simply follows the mouse. One If you don't like this, you could calculate how far the mouse is (vertically and horizontally) from the canvas centre, then use a small percentage of these values to position the dot away from the centre, effectively requiring more mouse movement to move the dot, which might feel more "natural".

Another idea may be to "snap" the dot's position to the nearest of the four arrow buttons (N,S,E,W), or even include the points in between (NE,SE,SW,NW).